# Why does built in Azure AD B2C profile edit policy show empty looking login screen?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a simple built-in profile edit policy: no social IdP, with custom UI screens.
Why is the first screen the user sees a Microsoft branded login screen, but without all of the usual input labels, headers and footers. The screen is basically an image, two empty boxes and a sign in button.

[image: screenshot of edit policy]

Have I made an error when configuring the policy? My single sign-on tab has been left to it's defaults. for both sign in and the profile edit policy.

Is this page necessary? If I am coming to this page after recently going through a sign in policy for this tenant, shouldn't SSO just move me to the profile edit screen?

If it is required; can we brand this screen as well using the built in policy? Or at least have the appropriate input labels in the boxes: "Email" and "Password"?

Comment: thanks spottedmahn for uploading the screenshot =D

Comment: learned that i should be excluding: prompt=login from my url. time to test new things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with the URL I was using. The default link in the Azure portal is not an SSO compatible link, because it includes the url parameter: **prompt=login**.  By **removing it**, it will check for an already logged in user, and bypass login.

If anybody else has issues here, you want to also make sure your SSO Config is set to Tenant or Application, or else the sign-in policy cookie won't get used in the profile edit policy